# Again: Easy way to request JSON with posting data

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I´m really new to Xcode and Objective-C ... I receive an JSON-Array to show the contents in my TableView:

in my `-viewDidLoad`:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Kategorien";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.visualstudio-teschl.at/apptest/kats.php"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];   
if(jsonData != nil)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    _kategorien = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
}
```

and in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSDictionary *data = [self.kategorien objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [data objectForKey:@"KAT_NAME"];

return cell;
```

It works great and shows my Strings (key -> KAT_NAME) in my Table.

But: How can i send a String with my request? For example i want to send "searchnumber = 2" with my request, like an ajax-request with javascript/jquery?

I searched but only could find examples that are to difficult (and maybe to oversized?) for my needs... is there no easy way like my request and ad something like "sendWithData" or is this method completely different with my simple request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to POST data, you'll need to create a NSMutableURLRequest object. You shouldn't use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] anyway as this creates a synchronous request and blocks the UI. Even though it's a little more code, this is the right way to do it:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.visualstudio-teschl.at/apptest/kats.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [@"searchnumber=2" dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:
  ^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // do something with data
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Will test it today :)

Will this send the "searchnumber" to my php? There i have for example:


$infoNumber = $_POST['searchnumber'];

Comment: ok... tried the Answer from lassej and it works :-D
but i have some problems in my brain today i think :( ...

... the NSLog gives me the right data ... but i can't use this array outside of viewDidLoad?

If i try use NSLog(@"%@",_pois); outside of viewDidLoad nothing is shown in my Log?

Inside my .h ->
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pois;

... What i added in "do something with data":

_pois = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

Comment: The completionHandler block is executed after viewDidLoad is finished (because it's asynchronous). So in that block you'll need to assign the data to your instance variable: "self.kategorien = ..." and then call something like "[self.tableView reloadData]".

Comment: the only thing: now i get to much rows... it's not really a problem ;) ... if i try "NSLog(@"numberOfRows %u",self.pois.count);" in my numberOfRowsInSection, i get first "0" and then a second time the right number. This means that this step is called twice?

Comment: yes, but that's intended. the first time you haven't loaded the data yet, so the table is empty. The second time is for displaying the loaded data.